# LibGDX: Particle in html project

Tags: libgdx

In desktop and Android is Ok but in Html not work and freezing in this line:

```
ParticleEffect particleEffect = new ParticleEffect();
articleEffect.load(Gdx.files.internal("particles/heart.p"), textureAtlas);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The js console gives you an error message.

Probably you are using a pre-1.9.10 particle effect with libgdx >= 1.9.10. The file format was changed, and while it was made backwards compatible on JVM platforms, this was not possible on HTML. You have to load and save the effect with the particle editor to solve this.